# Flask always hangs while handling two or more requests from Axios.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flask, axios

I have a problem in flask and axios. I have two projects, they are frontend (Reactjs) and backend (flask). In my case, my backend (flask) is always hanging when my frontend makes several requests using Axios.get(). I don't know why it could be like that. Because in my other project it's working fine.

This is my reactjs code that is using Axios:

```html
componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+"v1/total-production?date="+date)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({totalProductionToday: res.data})
            })
        
        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+"v1/product-trend-this-week")
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({totalProductionThisWeek: res.data})
            })

        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+"v1/product-trend-this-week")
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({productTrend: res.data})
            })

        Axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL+`v1/export-estimation?cw=${cw}&prd=${prd}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({exportEstimation: res.data})
            })
    }
```

Is there any advice for me? Because my goal is that my frontend can make several requests in one time without waiting for other requests to be done.

Comment: How are you running your flask app? it seems like you need to use a wsgi server, like gunicorn, to use multiple workers and accept multiple requests.

Comment: i ran my flask with execute main file, for example: python app.py. do i have to run it with wsgi server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask's development server only accepts one request at a time. You should try gunicorn its super easy

Install

```
pip install gunicorn
```

Just run gunicorn with more than one worker

```
gunicorn --workers 3 app:app
```

make sure to change your flask's module(app:app)

Hope it helps

Comment: i have followed your instructions. But, i still getting erros. When i run gunicorn --workers 3 app:app, it shows "gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>"

Comment: Can you post me the full traceback?

Comment: oh sorry, now i change my directory structure and it works. thanks!!!